# Javascript if invalid date fill with null

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

I have a date object from an html form.

```
const start = new Date(document.querySelector('input[name="start"]').value)
```

If the start time is left blank, I want the value returned to be an empty string. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
const value = document.querySelector('input[name="start"]').value
let start = ''
if (value !== '') {
  start = new Date(document.querySelector('input[name="start"]').value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check upon the input value before using it into the `Date` constructor:

```
const start = document.querySelector('input[name="start"]').value !== "" ? new Date(document.querySelector('input[name="start"]').value): "";
```

**Demo:**

```js
function logIt() {
  const start = document.querySelector('input[name="start"]').value !== "" ? new Date(document.querySelector('input[name="start"]').value) : "";
  console.log(start);
}
logIt();
```

```html
<input name="start" type="date" onchange="logIt()" />
```